# SWT, multiple threads, and exceptions

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, swt

I'm using SWT in a main GUI program.  Within it, I create another thread to run some programs.  However, if some errors are encountered in those processes, I want to report this to the user by making a message box appear.  Because in SWT, only a single thread can perform GUI operations, I was having the program runner throw exceptions, so the GUI thread could deal with them.  However, I am having problems because I create a new thread for the program runner (in order not to hold up the GUI thread, which will be continuously updating and refreshing some graphics), but as a result, the exceptions that take place are stuck as part of that thread, which can not create the error message box.  Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

```java
private void goButtonActionPerformed()
{
    // create the program runner object
    ProgramRunner PR = new ProgramRunner(); // real code passes in data to be used

    try{
        // check all necessary parameters are entered
        boolean paramsOK = PR.checkParams();
        if (paramsOK)
        {
            // all necessary information is available.  Start Processing.
            Thread t = new Thread() {
                public void run()
                {
                    try{
                        PR.runPrograms();
                    }
                    catch (IOException iox)
                    {
                        // This does not work to catch & display the exceptions 
                        // which took place in PR.runPrograms(), because this 
                        // thread is not allowed to perform GUI operations.  
                        // However, I don't know how to pass this 
                        // exception / error notification out of this thread.
                        MessageBox mb = new MessageBox(m_Shell, SWT.ICON_ERROR);
                        mb.setMessage(iox.getMessage());
                        mb.open();
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException iox)
    {
        // this works to catch & display the exceptions which took place 
        // in PR.checkParams() because that is not a separate thread
        MessageBox mb = new MessageBox(m_Shell, SWT.ICON_ERROR);
        mb.setMessage(iox.getMessage());
        mb.open();
    }
```

Comment: Oh and I realize PR.checkParams() doesn't need to return a boolean to be checked, because instead of returning false, it would have simply thrown an exception to be handled here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap catch logic inside a Display.getDefault().asyncExec to display error messages on UI thread:

```java
Thread t = new Thread()
{
   public void run()
   {
        try
        {
            PR.runProgram();
        }
        catch ( final IOException iox )
        {
             Display.getDefault().asyncExec( new Runnable()
             {
                 public void run()
                 {
                     MessageBox mb = new MessageBox(m_Shell, SWT.ICON_ERROR);
                     mb.setMessage(iox.getMessage());
                     mb.open();

                 }
             });

        }
   }
});

t.start();
```

the exceptions can be displayed in UI thread then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to arrange that the UI code runs in the UI thread. You can do this using the `asyncExec` or `syncExec` methods of `Display`.

`syncExec` suspends the current thread until the UI code has been run. `asyncExec` does not suspend the thread and runs the UI code as soon as possible.

You can get the current display in any thread using `Display.getDefault()` so you might do something like:

```java
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() ->
 {
   if (m_Shell != null && !m_Shell.isDisposed()) {
     MessageBox mb = new MessageBox(m_Shell, SWT.ICON_ERROR);
     mb.setMessage(iox.getMessage());
     mb.open();
   }
 });
```

I have used a Java 8 lambda expression for the `Runnable` here as it is shorter than the traditional method.

Since this code is being run asynchronously it is good practice to check that the shell is not null and has not been disposed.